# Docker container in priviledged mode not showing udev symlinks

Tags: docker, udev

I'm running a docker container for an application that requires direct access to `/dev/ttyACM0`. Because of that I'm running the container with `--privileged` to allow it access to the `/dev` of the host.

> When the operator executes docker run --privileged, Docker will enable
>   to access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration
>   in AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same
>   access to the host as processes running outside containers on the
>   host.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

However, the device is sometimes given a different name on the host (`/dev/ttyACM1`, `/dev/ttyACM2`) which crashes the Docker application statically  depending on the path `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Because of that I've created a udev rule that always maps the device to `/dev/mydevice` on the host, regardless of what `/dev/ttyACMx`. However link to the device isn't accessible in the container.

```
host$ ls -la /dev/ttyACM1 
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 166, 1 Mai 24 22:33 /dev/ttyACM1
host$ ls -la /dev/mydevice 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mai 24 22:33 /dev/mydevice -> ttyACM1

container# ls -la /dev/ttyACM1
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 166, 1 May 24 20:13 /dev/ttyACM1
container# ls -la /dev/mydevice
ls: cannot access /dev/mydevice: No such file or directory
```

What is incorrect with the above approach?

Comment: just to clarify - if I understand correctly, you are running your container with a volume on /dev/mydevice? e.g. with the command-line argument `-v /dev/mydevice:/dev/mydevice` ? if you are using the --device flag, it seems that it doesn't support symbolic links for now: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13840

Comment: @christophetd Updated with definition of priviledged

Answer (score 1):

Docker's `--privileged` creates a tmpfs inside the container and recreates all device nodes currently in the hosts `/dev`. However, it does not create or update symlinks from hosts `/dev`.

You can however bind mount real /dev inside the container using `-v /dev:/dev` to get all device and symlinks inside the container (with the caveat that you expose real `/dev` inside the container).